# Login Form- Not working if else statements

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, forms, authentication

I cant get my login form to work with the separate logins, the preview wont event show up. I think there is something wrong with my if-else statements.

HTML:

```
<body ng-app="myApplication" ng-controller="myController" ng-cloak>


<h3>Contact Us</h3>
<div id="showDiv" ng-show="firstPage">
  <form>
    <label for="name">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your name" ng-model="name"><br>
    <label for="email">Email:</label>
    <input type="email" placeholder="Enter your email" ng-model="email"><br>
    <label for="number">Number:</label>
    <input type="number" placeholder="Enter your number" ng-model="phoneNumber"><br>
    <label for="issue">Issue:</label>
    <textarea name="issue" rows="5" cols="20" placeholder="Enter your issue" ng-model="issue"></textarea>
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit" ng-click="showHide()">
    <input type="reset" value="Reset" id="reset">
  </form>  
</div>

<div id="hideDiv" ng-show="secondPage">
  <p ng-bind="feedback"></p>
  <p>Your contact details are:</p>
  <p>Email: <span ng-bind='email'></span></p>
  <p>Phone Number: <span ng-bind='phoneNumber'></span></p>
  <p>Your issue is:</p> 
  <p><span ng-bind='issue'></span></p>
  <input type="submit" value="Go Back" id="goBack" ng-click="hideShow()" />
</div>
```

Javascipt:

```js
<script>
angular.module('myApplication', []).controller('myController', function($scope){
  $scope.name = "";
  $scope.email = "";
  $scope.phoneNumber = "";
  $scope.issue = "";

  $scope.firstPage = true;
  $scope.secondPage = false;

  $scope.showHide = function() 
  {
    $scope.firstPage = false; 
    $scope.secondPage = true; 
    $scope.feedback = "";

    if ($scope.name = "Po Lu" && $scope.email = "Po.Tom@acc.ac.au" && $scope.phonenumber = "021") {
          $scope.feedback = "Thanks for contacting, " + $scope.name + ". We're working to fix your issue already." ;
        }
      else if ($scope.name == "Mel Tom" && $scope.email = "Mel.Tom@acc.ac.au" && $scope.phonenumber = "0217") {
          $scope.feedback = "Thanks for contacting, " + $scope.name + ". We're working to fix your issue already." ;
        }
      else {
          $scope.firstPage = true;
          $scope.secondPage = false;
          alert("Please Enter valid details");
        }

  }

  $scope.hideShow = function() 
  {
    $scope.firstPage = true; 
    $scope.secondPage = false; 

    $scope.name = "";
    $scope.email = "";
    $scope.phoneNumber = "";
    $scope.issue = "";
  }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Do you get any error in console?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Below are the mistakes made.

1. inside the if conditions, we should never use assignment `=`, but use conditional operators such as `==` or `===`(strict type checking!)
2. Number type input won't allow zeros in the beginning, so I changed it from "021" to "21"
3. phoneNumber variable is set to `phoneNumber` in html, but in js its `phonenumber`  so I changed it!
4. Finally I'm using double equals inside the if condition,so that type won't be an issue, we can compare number to string, if you want you can strictly check the types!

```js
angular.module('myApplication', []).controller('myController', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = "";
  $scope.email = "";
  $scope.phoneNumber = "";
  $scope.issue = "";

  $scope.firstPage = true;
  $scope.secondPage = false;

  $scope.showHide = function() {
    $scope.firstPage = false;
    $scope.secondPage = true;
    $scope.feedback = "";
    if ($scope.name == "Po Lu" && $scope.email == "Po.Tom@acc.ac.au" && $scope.phoneNumber == "21") {
      $scope.feedback = "Thanks for contacting, " + $scope.name + ". We're working to fix your issue already.";
    } else if ($scope.name == "Mel Tom" && $scope.email == "Mel.Tom@acc.ac.au" && $scope.phoneNumber == "217") {
      $scope.feedback = "Thanks for contacting, " + $scope.name + ". We're working to fix your issue already.";
    } else {
      $scope.firstPage = true;
      $scope.secondPage = false;
      alert("Please Enter valid details");
    }

  }

  $scope.hideShow = function() {
    $scope.firstPage = true;
    $scope.secondPage = false;

    $scope.name = "";
    $scope.email = "";
    $scope.phoneNumber = "";
    $scope.issue = "";
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.7/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApplication" ng-controller="myController" ng-cloak>


  <h3>Contact Us</h3>
  <div id="showDiv" ng-show="firstPage">
    <form>
      <label for="name">Name:</label>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your name" ng-model="name"><br>
      <label for="email">Email:</label>
      <input type="email" placeholder="Enter your email" ng-model="email"><br>
      <label for="number">Number:</label>
      <input type="number" placeholder="Enter your number" ng-model="phoneNumber"><br>
      <label for="issue">Issue:</label>
      <textarea name="issue" rows="5" cols="20" placeholder="Enter your issue" ng-model="issue"></textarea>
      <br>
      <br>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit" ng-click="showHide()">
      <input type="reset" value="Reset" id="reset">
    </form>
  </div>

  <div id="hideDiv" ng-show="secondPage">
    <p ng-bind="feedback"></p>
    <p>Your contact details are:</p>
    <p>Email: <span ng-bind='email'></span></p>
    <p>Phone Number: <span ng-bind='phoneNumber'></span></p>
    <p>Your issue is:</p>
    <p><span ng-bind='issue'></span></p>
    <input type="submit" value="Go Back" id="goBack" ng-click="hideShow()" />
  </div>
</div>
```